# Javascript code killing my websites Google Page Speed Score

Tags: javascript, wordpress

The following code is somehow making my Google Page Speed Score drop by 10 points. It resides in the footer of a WordPress website between script tags with no enqueuing. The code makes the navigation behave more like a burger menu on mobile device.

```
<script>
(function() {
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j('body').addClass('js');
  var $menu = $j('#menu'),
    $menulink = $j('.menu-link');

$menulink.click(function() {
  $menulink.toggleClass('active');
  $menu.toggleClass('active');
  return false;
});});

})();
 </script>
```

Can anyone see any glaring errors with the code or are there any other recommendations.

Comment: nothing glaringly obvious What does Google Page Speed say the problems are? And how many menu-links are on the page?

Comment: There is only one instance of menu-link on the page and GPS says

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Show how to fix
Reduce server response time
Show how to fix
Prioritize visible content
Show how to fix
Leverage browser caching
Show how to fix

Comment: If possible, try moving the script right to the very bottom of the html, rather than in the footer. See if that works